# Is there a way to read files with different filenames and plot them on the same graph?

Tags: python, plot

I want to produce a plot of a number of geometries which consist of a cloud of points (formatted point data). I managed to plot only on geometry on a graph, but couldn't do it for all 4 geometries I have.

I've tried using the glob function, but I don't know how to make it work with my problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.chdir(os.getcwd())
plt.close()
f = open('Geom_0_geo.fpd','r')
lines = f.readlines()
x,y=[],[]
x_int,y_int=[],[]
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    if len(line) == 3:
        x_int.append(line[0])
        y_int.append(line[1])
    else:
        x.append(x_int)
        y.append(y_int)
        x_int,y_int=[],[]
    if line == lines[-1].split():
        x.append(x_int)
        y.append(y_int)


f.close()

for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'k',lw=1.5)
    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_xlim([-2,3.5])
    axes.set_ylim([0,3])
```

The geometry filenames are like Geom_0.geo.fpd,Geom_1.geo.fpd, Geom_2.geo.fpd etc. I want to plot them all on the same graph but with different line colours and a label assigned to each. What is the best possible way to do this? The code I've shown is only for one geometry which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a try of below,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import glob
#file = glob.glob("/path/*.fpd")
file = ['Geom_0.geo.fpd','Geom_1.geo.fpd', 'Geom_2.geo.fpd',... ]
# set up the line style, make sure len(mark)= len(file)
ls = ['-', '--', ':' , ...]
# set up color make sure len(color)= len(file)
color = ['r','g','b',...]
# set up labels
tag = ['tag1',...]
for i in range(0, len(file)):
    f = open(file[i],'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    x,y=[],[]
    x_int,y_int=[],[]
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        if len(line) == 3:
            x_int.append(line[0])
            y_int.append(line[1])
        else:
            x.append(x_int)
            y.append(y_int)
            x_int,y_int=[],[]
        if line == lines[-1].split():
            x.append(x_int)
            y.append(y_int)


    f.close()

    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.plot(x[i],y[i],lw=1.5, linestyle=ls[i], color[i], label = tag[i])
        axes = plt.gca()
        axes.set_xlim([-2,3.5])
        axes.set_ylim([0,3])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted it to. What should I do if I wanted to plot each geometry with different linetype and line colours? Lastly, what is the best way to assign labels?

Comment: Thanks again for your response. However, I get the following error when running yoru code :    plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'k',lw=1.5, mark[i], color[i], label = tag[i])
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Comment: @Mason Hold on.

Comment: @Mason Is there error with`plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'k',lw=1.5, mark[i], label = tag[i])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197689/discussion-between-mason-and-complicatedphenomenon).